# Установка linux на планшет

Tags: linux

Добрый день. Подскажите, можно ли установить linux на виндовс планшеты или на таких устройств другая архитектура?

Comment: Какая модель планшета, можно узнать?

Comment: Скорее всего архитектура там поддерживаемая линухом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем случае поставить можно, правда есть несколько нюансов - если планшет с UEFI, то придется повозиться, ну и самый плохой случай - может быть производителем заблокирован BIOS или запрещена загрузка с флешек, так что надо рассматривать конкретную модель отдельно. А так проблем возникнуть не должно, даже если ARM процессор, главное подходящий дистрибутив подобрать